# Java HttpClient не хватает памяти при обмене файлами

Tags: java, http, httpclient, outofmemoryerror

Я пересылаю файлы по HTTP при помощи апачевского HttpClient'а, и при обмене гиговыми файлами JVM не хватает памяти. Увеличил размер хипа при помощи ключа `-Xmx`, но это не помогло.

**Вот такой код:**

```
public String commit(String remoteFileTempId, String hash) {
    try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder
                .get(commit)
                .addHeader("fileTempId", remoteFileTempId)
                .addHeader("hash", hash)
                .build();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return response.getFirstHeader("fileId").getValue();
        }
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public FileModel download(String remoteFileId) {
    try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(commonfs + remoteFileId);
        FileModel downloaded = client.execute(request, new FileDownloadHandler());
        return downloaded;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

static class FileDownloadHandler implements ResponseHandler<FileModel> {

    public FileModel handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        FileModel model = new FileModel(response.getFirstHeader("name").getValue(),
                response.getFirstHeader("creator").getValue(),
                response.getFirstHeader("hash").getValue(),
                response.getFirstHeader("sysId").getValue());

        File file = new File(Config.TEMP_DIR + model.getName());
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, file);

        model.setPath(Config.TEMP_DIR + model.getName());

        return model;
    }
}
```

Где здесь может быть перерасход памяти?

**Текст ошибки:**

```
com.vaadin.server.UploadException: Upload failed
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.streamToReceiver(FileUploadHandler.java:631)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.handleFileUploadValidationAndData(FileUploadHandler.java:460)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.doHandleSimpleMultipartFileUpload(FileUploadHandler.java:413)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.handleRequest(FileUploadHandler.java:290)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method uploadSucceeded in GP.ui.component.Uploader failed.
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:519)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:237)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1014)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Upload.fireUploadSuccess(Upload.java:830)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Upload$2.streamingFinished(Upload.java:1118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.streamToReceiver(FileUploadHandler.java:604)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.file.Files.read(Files.java:3099)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3158)
    at GP.ui.component.Uploader.uploadSucceeded(Uploader.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:499)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:237)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1014)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Upload.fireUploadSuccess(Upload.java:830)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Upload$2.streamingFinished(Upload.java:1118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.streamToReceiver(FileUploadHandler.java:604)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.handleFileUploadValidationAndData(FileUploadHandler.java:460)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.doHandleSimpleMultipartFileUpload(FileUploadHandler.java:413)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.handleRequest(FileUploadHandler.java:290)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
```

Comment: ` InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();` - не закрыт. `HttpUriRequest request` может тоже надо закрывать.

Comment: @Tsyklop там ниже используется `FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile`, который закрывает стрим.

Comment: @typemoon добавь полное сообщение с ошибкой

Comment: @Mychel_T, добавил

Answer (score 1):

Судя по стэку вы используете неверный код

```
java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3158)
```

Вот что по этому поводу сказано в javadoc:

> #### [readAllBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path))
>
> Читает все байты из файла. Метод гарантирует, что файл закрыт, когда
> все байты были прочитаны или ошибка ввода-вывода или другое исключение
> среды выполнения.
>
> Обратите внимание, что этот метод предназначен для простых случаев,
> когда удобно считать все байты в массив байтов. Он не предназначен для
> чтения больших файлов.

Comment: [Что означает если ответ "принят"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = client.execute(targetHost, httpget);
System.out.println("Body: " + EntityUtils.toString(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity()));
System.out.println("Code: " + httpResponse.code());

EntityUtils.consume(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity());
```

Метод `EntityUtils.consume()` обеспечивает полное потребление содержимого `HttpEntity`, и закрытие потока, если он существует. Метод отрабатывает тихо, без каких-либо исключений `IOException`.